# Array in Objective C and getting certain things out of it

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

I have an array coming out of a MSQuery and it comes up like this:

[image]

I need to get out of it the barID from the 3 columns and place them in another array or dictionary so i can do a for loop on them.

Comment: Show the code that does the logging. You appear to be logging 3 different dictionaries... How did you try to extract `barID` and what went wrong?

Comment: well there are three dictionaries in the array and I need to extract the BarID from each one, so I can do another query.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the following code:

```
NSArray *test = @[@{@"barID": @1}, @{@"barID": @2}, @{@"barID": @3}];
NSLog(@"test: %@", test);
NSLog(@"test barIDs: %@", [test valueForKey:@"barID"]);
```

This produces the following output:

```
test: (
    {
        barID = 1;
    },
    {
        barID = 2;
    },
    {
        barID = 3;
    }
)

test barIDs: (
    1,
    2,
    3
)
```

So you can see that when I do `valueForKey:`, it will create a new `NSArray` containing the values of the `barID` key in each of the dictionaries.

Comment: bingo! the valueforKey works and shows the three ids, so can i now create this an another array ?

Comment: @user3229170 What do you mean by "create this is another array"?

Comment: @user3229170, `valueForKey:` returns an array so you don't need to create another array from what it returns...

Comment: because I need to split the 3 BarIDs , so summat like BarID(1), BarID(2), BarID(3). Because I need to run another SQL query 3 times with that BarID.

Comment: I need each one to go into NSDictionary *barIDDictionary = @{ @"myParam": barID};